# WPF - setting visibility on code behind for a WebBrowser not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visibility

I have two elements, a WebBrowser and a Slider, and I'm trying to hide one and show the other depending on which type of document a user opens, a PDF or a video file (mp4). But, currently, when I open a PDF file the WebBrowser remains hidden.

In MainWindow.xaml, I have

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="PDFView" Width="600" 
                    Height="410" Visibility="{Binding PDFVisible}">
</WebBrowser>

<FFmpegFramework:MediaElement Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MediaElement"
                    Height="400" Background="Gray"  Visibility="{Binding VideoVisible}"/>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs, I have

```
else if (fileName.Contains("pdf"))
{

    MainWindowViewModel dataContext = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
    dataContext.PDFVisible = Visibility.Visible;
    dataContext.VideoVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;

    //PDFView.Navigate("file:///" + fileName);
}
else if (fileName.Contains("mp4"))
{
    MainWindowViewModel dataContext = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
    dataContext.PDFVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
    dataContext.VideoVisible = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

In MainWindowModel.cs, I have:

```
public Visibility PDFVisible
{
    get
    {
        return fPDFVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetProperty<Visibility>(ref fPDFVisible, value);
    }
}

public Visibility VideoVisible
{
    get
    {
        return fVideoVisible;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetProperty<Visibility>(ref fVideoVisible, value);
    }
}

private Visibility fPDFVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
private Visibility fVideoVisible = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Does the mainviewmodel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: It implements BindableBase, which I just looked up and that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: btw why are you doing the changes in xaml.cs and not in the view model?

Comment: can you elaborate? xaml.cs (the code behind, where the file type is selected) is changing the view model, which I thought in turn should change the binded attributes in XAML. Am I missing something here? how would you do it?

Comment: Are you sure that your 'else if' code blocks are actually executed? Also make sure that the DataContext of the PDFView control is the same instance of the MainWindowViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this changes in .xaml.cs file than why are you create `objects` to change `visibility`. you can directly change `visibility` by name of control

```
if (fileName.Contains("pdf"))
{
    PDFView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    MediaElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
else if (fileName.Contains("mp4"))
{
    PDFView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    MediaElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and dont forget to change 'Mode=TwoWay' in binding. it will also changed property in `ViewModel`

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="PDFView" Width="600" 
            Height="410" Visibility="{Binding PDFVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<FFmpegFramework:MediaElement Grid.Row="0" x:Name="MediaElement"
                 Height="400" Background="Gray"  Visibility="{Binding VideoVisible, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```